# slice up twitter bootstrap to increase page load speed

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have designed my website to optimize the above the fold content by only using a tiny fraction of the twitter bootstrap framework above the fold of my site, then using some of the rest of it below the fold.

I used a floating nav bar that shrinks, some elements from the container class and that's all the twitter bootstrap content that's loaded above the fold.

I was wondering could I edit the bootstrap.css file to take out those portions and inline them in the head of my html page, then defer the loading of the rest of the css since I don't need it so fast.

My question; is it possible to edit the twitter bootstrap and just strip off the necessary parts to load first without wrecking bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, of course it is ok.

Comment: Inlining them will make things *slower*. You'll be sending all that CSS over the wire for every pageview, instead of once for a cached CSS file. This is a really, really bad way of handling things.

Comment: @ceejayoz  nginx handles caches pretty well plus i would more likely just minify the part that loads above the fold and place that into the header of the webpage and then lazily load the rest after everything else.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith care to elaborate on that please?

Comment: @user1610950 If you want to spend hours figuring out how to do this only to discard the entire thing because it hurt performance, go ahead. Just trying to save you the time and frustration. Bootstrap is ~25 kilobytes minified and gzipped - hardly extravagant.

Comment: -4 on this question..... I never got the point of down voting a question but whatever. I'll figure it out myself.

Comment: @user1610950 the downvotes are most likely because this is not a specific "coding" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are micro-optimizations which are only going to cause you headaches for very little, if any, benefit.

Unless you have a website which is serving millions of users a day or is displaying tonnes of content at once (and I really do mean tonnes, in which case, simplify your site!) you will see no real benefit with what you are proposing.

What you can do is be clever about what you optimize and how. For a start, if your entire site is only using certain portions of Bootstrap (i.e. you never use Modals), make a custom build of Bootstrap from their website with the stuff you don't want stripped out. This will give you a smaller set of files and therefore you'll send less down the wire to the user, speeding up your site.

Alternatively, if you are using large amounts of the library you could just use their existing CDN (content distribution network). This will serve the js/css files from a single url that many people are using, which has the double benefit that you don't have to serve any content from your own server, just link to someone elses, and also there's a good chance that if the user visited a site that has used that same CDN their browser would have cached it, making it appear without *any* network calls. Now that's speedy!

In the end, there are a whole host of things you would be better tasked at optimizing before even thinking about this kind of thing. I recommend you take a good look at the [YSlow plugin](http://yslow.org/) and best practices. There are loads of things there that you can do to optimize your site without hacking apart Bootstrap just for 'above the fold' content.

Comment: Thanks a lot, a very detailed answer that definitely helped me sort out the issue.